# Multiple layers of license plates on egypt cars

Tags: automobiles, egypt, cairo

I have spent a week travelling through Egypt and saw that, especially in Cairo, there are quite a lot of cars and trucks which have multiple layers of license plates (multiple license plates on top of each others). In almost every case its a license plate from Germany or the Netherlands, sometimes even both, which are covered over by a smaller egyptian license plate.

How does this make any sense?

Answer (score 6):

It means nothing, really nothing. They are sold in car accessories shops and some people put them because they think it's "cool".

It's usually done by van owners (the vans that are used for shared transportation for a small fee, like public transportation but owned by individuals), taxi drivers and truck owners. The pattern here is people who usually make a living by their cars, their car feels like home or something, they want to decorate it.

I am not Egyptian, but I lived there for a few years.